# How do I build a report viewer in an ASP.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, reportviewer

I am trying to build a report viewer in an ASP.net page. When I drag ReportViewer to my aspx page, instead of the smart tag populating with options to select, I get a box stating `Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1 Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`.

Then I realize that ReportViewer from toolbox is actually version 9.0.0.0. But when I check at Package Manager Console, it state that
`PM> install-package microsoft.report.viewer
'Microsoft.Report.Viewer 11.0.0.0' already installed.
Task1 already has a reference to 'Microsoft.Report.Viewer 11.0.0.0'.`

This is a new local install with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and SQL Server 2008. I installed Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008.

Has anyone seen this or know the cause? I have searched everywhere.

I have tried to download and install ReportViewer 8.0.0.0, 10.0.0.0, 11.0.0.0, 12.0.0.0 but I still get a box stating `Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

Here is my Web.config:

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
  </assemblies>
```

Comment: In the Toolbox menu, right click and select "Choose Items" option and select the target version that you want, which would add the required version of the control. Then try the drag and drop option.

Comment: I have selected report.viewer 11.0.0.0 and drag/drop report viewer from toolbox but still get "Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'"

Comment: Try adding the control info manually to the ".designer" file which might resolve the issue

Comment: How to do that? I'm a newbie on this, sorry because I'll need more details direction and explanation from you.

Comment: Open "<Filename>.aspx.designer.cs" which already has some controls that are added to the aspx page. Add this ReportViewer property there similar to other controls.

Comment: Now I get new problem, it state that "Error Creating Control - ReportViewer2Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." after I choose version 11.0.0.0

Comment: You should give the same control id as the one you have added on the aspx page. It should be ReportViewer1

Comment: Before I change ReportViewer 9.0.0.0 to 11.0.0.0, the webconfig able to display <assemblies>, but after I install ReportViewer 11.0.0.0, it show nothing at <assemblies> and at "<%@ Register assembly=" aspx.
But ReportViewer at toolbox already update to 11.0.0.0 and DLL at Bin also using version 11.0.0.0. I tried install version 9 but nothing work so I change it to 11.0.0.0. 
But its getting worst I guess. Help me, been stuck on this almost 3 days.